# A fatal error in Junit with objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, objectify

I cannot discover why my integrations tests with objectify that are crashing.
There is no problem when is executed one by one or debuging.

That is the objectify code.

```
protected void before() throws Throwable {
    original = ObjectifyService.factory();
    ObjectifyFactory factory = newObjectifyFactory();
    for (Class<?> type : register) {
        factory.register(type);
    }
    ObjectifyService.setFactory(factory);
    closeable = ObjectifyService.begin();
}

protected void after() {
    ObjectifyService.setFactory(original);
    closeable.close();
}
```

After some tests the runner stop and i receive this message.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000003, pid=15104, tid=9848
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000003
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as: Compiled method (nm)    7403  625     n       java.lang.Class::isInstance (native)  total in heap  [0x0000000002b4bf10,0x0000000002b4c2b8] = 936 relocation     [0x0000000002b4c030,0x0000000002b4c088] = 88  main code [0x0000000002b4c0a0,0x0000000002b4c2b8] = 536 Compiled method (c2)    7404  752             java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction::invoke_L_L (28 bytes)  total in heap  [0x0000000002c38490,0x0000000002c38778] = 744  relocation     [enter image description here][1][0x0000000002c385b0,0x0000000002c385d0] = 32  main code [0x0000000002c385e0,0x0000000002c38660] = 128  stub code      [0x0000000002c38660,0x0000000002c38698] = 56  oops           [0x0000000002c38698,0x0000000002c386a0] = 8  scopes data    [0x0000000002c386a0,0x0000000002c386e8] = 72  scopes pcs     [0x0000000002c386e8,0x0000000002c38748] = 96  dependencies   [0x0000000002c38748,0x0000000002c38750] = 8  handler table  [0x0000000002c38750,0x0000000002c38768] = 24  nul chk table  [0x0000000002c38768,0x0000000002c38778] = 16
```

Comment: Can you add code for 'newObjectifyFactory()' as well? 
Why are you creating new factory and what's the reasoning for resetting factory to original?

Comment: here is the code :
 protected ObjectifyFactory newObjectifyFactory() {
  return new ObjectifyFactory();
 }
 
But this is a example that i found in a researh to try solve the problem.

Before i was just using ObjectifyService.register();' and 'ObjectifyService.begin();'. It's enough, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are seeing here is a JVM bug. This is not supposed to be possible. Make sure you have the most recent version of the JDK installed, and if so, the only place you can really file an issue is with Oracle :-(

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will try to understand.
For now i gave up the memory storage and set the LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig to storage in file. This solved the problem.